Postfix does not work with SMTP authentication
We are using postfix without authenticacion and works correctly, but my company now requires smtp user/password.
I have configurated password file in /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
[smtp.domain1.com]:1025 app1@emaildomain.com:password
When i try to send email i got this message on log:
(Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=emaildomain.com type=AAAA: Host found but no data record of requested type)
emaildomain.com is not a DNS zone and you cant resolve it, but we can use it on this server without smtp authenticacion and in another servers with outlook for example.
This is my main.cf:
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version

# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# See http://www.postfix.org/COMPATIBILITY_README.html -- default to 2 on
# fresh installs.
compatibility_level = 2

# TLS parameters
# smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
# smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
# smtpd_tls_security_level=may
# smtp_tls_CApath=/etc/ssl/certs
# smtp_tls_security_level=may
# smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache


# smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
#  myhostname = Servername
 alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
 alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
 myorigin = /etc/mailname
 mydestination = $myhostname, localhost, Servername, emaildomain.com
 relayhost = [smtp.domain1.com]:1025
 smtp_use_tls = yes
 smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
 smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
 smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
 smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
 smtp_sasl_tls_security_options = noanonymous
 mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 ourIPrange
 mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all


(this is mostly comment but space/formatting limited)

my company now requires smtp user/password.

It would appear that you are trying to configure a satellite host to connect to a relay which now requires authentication (it would have been nice if you had stated this).
Obvious things to try are:

Escape the @ in the username
Omit "@emaildomain.com" from the username
Add a record in /etc/hosts for emaildomain.com


emaildomain.com is not a DNS zone and you cant resolve it

Your postfix logs are explicitly stating it CAN resolve it. And you have not addressed this in your post. This casts some doubt on your methodology.

I have set this setting to avoid the AAAA record problem: inet_protocols = ipv4.
About your advice, 1 and 2 doesnt solve the problem and 3 im able to resolv domain using postfix without auth, and i can solve smtp.domain1.com, i think this is important.

For those who are interested, I solved them by commenting out the lines "myorigin" and "smtp_tls_CAfile", deleting  emaildomain.com from "mydestination" and installing the sasl2-bin library
